# How to fix pylint logging-not-lazy?

Tags: python, pylint

I am using prospector to examine my code. Pylint returned a `logging-not-lazy` warning about my debug message.

```
Line: 31
  pylint: logging-not-lazy / Specify string format arguments as logging function parameters (col 16)   Line: 42
  pylint: logging-not-lazy / Specify string format arguments as logging function parameters (col 12)
```

My code is:

```
logging.debug("detect mimetypes faild because %s" % e )
```

How do I fix `logging-not-lazy` in pylint?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

This means, that you should rewrite your code as:

```
logging.debug("detect mimetypes faild because %s", e)
```

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

> **Logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)**
>
> ... Logs a message with level DEBUG on this logger. *The `msg` is the message format string, and the `args` are the arguments which are merged into msg using the string formatting operator.* (Note that this means that you can use keywords in the format string, together with a single dictionary argument.) ...

Comment: Is there a reason why this format is preferred for debug logs?

Comment: It's preferred because it's lazy. The logging library doesn't format the string at all if the level is not set to `DEBUG`. That means it doesn't have to do extra work unless the user really wants to see those log messages.