# Lazy evaluation of strings in python logging: comparing `%` with `.format`

Tags: python, string, logging

Is there any difference between these two calls:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().debug('test: %i' % 42)
```

and

```
logging.getLogger().debug('test: {}'.format(42))
```

Where we assume `42` is replaced by some long computation (say 7.5 million years of computation) when it is cast to a string that produces a final answer of 42.

Is the first approach lazily evaluated in case logging is set to debug?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714555/python-string-formatting-is-more-efficient-than-format-function , for performance, probably will want `f-strings` which are faster than these methods, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-in-python-3-6

Comment: Super useful reference, thanks RafaelC, though it hasn't clarified the lazy evaluation question.

Comment: In both of your examples, the formatted string gets fully evaluated by Python before the `logging` module gets involved in the process at all.  You probably want to pass the format string and its parameters as *separate parameters* to `.debug()`, so that it actually does the formatting - I assume that it only does this if the message isn't going to be filtered out, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: If you really want laziness, you need something like `if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG): …`. From your comments on the answers, though, it sounds like you don't need that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4148790/2864740, perhaps. Solutions also show a proxy-object to *defer the cost of value generation*. Of course, generating debug values should still be "relatively quick" and "side-effect free" or the very act of enabling debugging will still be problematic/unexpected..

Comment: Another related article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147442/how-to-fix-pylint-logging-not-lazy

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Neither are lazy. Both strings are interpolated before sent to logger. Lazy evaluation in terms of python logging is done with separate arguments. The documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html suggest the following for lazy evaluation of string interpolation;

```
logging.getLogger().debug('test: %i', 42)
```

**TL;DR**
In this case it’s easier to consider the following. We sent a primitive type (string) but only one argument to the logger. Thus it can’t be lazy.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.2+, [you can also do lazy evaluation with `str.format` style strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter), although `%`-style is still the default.

Comment: This is still *not lazy* in in the sense asked: `.debug('test: %i', takes_75_million_years_to_generate)` -- it only defers the creation of the *string* itself, not the generation of the value supplied as an argument, which is inconsequentially comparatively :} The original question is vague with "Where we assume 42 is replaced by some long computation (7.5 million years, for example) that produces a final answer of 42.", but once 42 is produced, the *cost has been paid*.

Comment: The original question was vague that way, my bad. I did only mean to ask about the evaluation of the string concatenation. Thank you bringing clarity to that point.

Comment: I added "when cast to a string" to the original question to clarify this detail.

Answer (score 5):

I'd take a look in the references I posted in the comments for more detailed information on `%` and `.format()`.

For the lazy evaluation question, the answer is *no*.

A simple test will do

```
def func1(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return(x)

def func2(x):
    #time.sleep(5)
    return(x)

%timeit 'debug1: %s' % func1(3)
5 s ± 1.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit 'debug2: {}'.format(func1(3))
5 s ± 1.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit 'debug1: %s' % func2(3)
297 ns ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit 'debug2: {}'.format(func2(3))
404 ns ± 4.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

In both `.format` (obviously) and `%` approaches,`func()` is calculated anyway.